# Alternative to partial dependence plots

Tags: statistics, explainable-ai

In my understanding, to make the partial dependence plot, you select a feature of interest x and leave other features X unchanged, then for each example in the validation dataset you sample values in the range of x, and compute the average models outputs for each value.

The problem with this is that it can lead to absurd data points when the features are correlated and you sample arbitrary values of x.

Why not instead keep the values of x unchanged, and just bin the examples based on the values of x, and compute the average model output for each group. Would this plot make more sense when the features are correlated? Would it be meaningful at all?